# How do you add a background image to a div in Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: html, background, zurb-foundation

This seems like it'd be terribly easy but I couldn't get the standard method to work?

**HTML**

```
[div class="test"] [/div]
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/ISSFinalConfigEnd2006.jpg);
     z-index: -1000;
}
```

I had to use square brackets because the greater than/less than brackets would not show up in this textfield.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Foundation, it's a CSS issue.

If you want to add a background image to your site (I guess that's the point), why don't you simply do this:

```
body {
background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/ISSFinalConfigEnd2006.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Additionally: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Thanks!  I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 with Superscrollorama.  I think it's the only way to pin backgrounds with Supercrollorama.  You create divs and then add a background to the div, at least that's what I derived from their examples.  In the Superscrollorama example, they create a solid color background.  However, I copied the example code directly into my HTML and it didn't work.  Neither the the div nor the background showed up.  http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: using both zurb and superscrollorama can comlicate ur css styles makes sure of the overrides..